# Mac OS X - Lion: Possible to disable scroll wheel?

Tags: macos, mouse, scrolling, zoom

Is it possible to disable the scroll wheel on my bluetooth mouse for my iMac? I remote desktop into a computer at work (windows xp) to run some mapping software (ArcGIS 10), and the mouse wheel controls the zoom level (scale) of the map. The only problem is the mouse wheel is extremely sensitive and is constantly zooming in and out of my map document. The document has a lot of data in it and when I'm working with large files this can cause long redraw times.

I've also noticed it does the same thing when using google maps in OS X, which is also very frustrating. It would be nice if there was some way to bind this option to a key command so I could enable/disable quickly as needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is in 'Universal Access' in System Preferences. In the 'Mouse' tab there is a button that says 'Mouse Options', and the option to disable scrolling.

Apparently, which options are visible will change depending on the hardware, so that doesn't mean it will definitely be visible to you, but it's worth a try!